# Visualising and Understanding a 3D Array / Tensor in Numpy / Matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I have data in an hdf5 file that I have converted into a numpy array of shape (57, 90, 128).

Here's the 3D array labelled x:

```
[[[41.9384   41.272415 40.617287 ... 48.844627 49.244698 49.661514]
  [41.397217 40.723698 40.063335 ... 48.1394   48.545223 48.967934]
  [40.870575 40.188343 39.519466 ... 47.44466  47.85631  48.28499 ]
  ...
  [43.442932 42.55078  41.66337  ... 37.415535 38.148727 38.89263 ]
  [43.761475 42.87579  41.994297 ... 37.902004 38.627724 39.36299 ]
  [44.100094 43.220413 42.346016 ... 38.408096 39.12455  39.85264 ]]

 [[41.44701  40.775562 40.11295  ... 48.26646  48.67123  49.092865]
  [40.900696 40.22024  39.55203  ... 47.552746 47.963478 48.39122 ]
  [40.371548 39.68155  39.004093 ... 46.849396 47.26618  47.700108]
  ...
  [43.12938  42.23068  41.33658  ... 36.93269  37.674095 38.426914]
  [43.450195 42.558193 41.671036 ... 37.426445 38.15917  38.90268 ]
  [43.791267 42.906277 42.025517 ... 37.938747 38.66349  39.397842]]

 [[40.97391  40.294678 39.6272   ... 47.702103 48.111572 48.53802 ]
  [40.42128  39.73272  39.057457 ... 46.979904 47.395554 47.82832 ]
  [39.885853 39.188004 38.50331  ... 46.26794  46.68986  47.12904 ]
  ...
  [42.836636 41.931736 41.0312   ... 36.469273 37.219494 37.981075]
  [43.159603 42.26154  41.3681   ... 36.969868 37.709877 38.46132 ]
  [43.50288  42.611694 41.72538  ... 37.488487 38.218582 38.96034 ]]

 ...

 [[42.853973 42.278515 41.718906 ... 46.573013 46.990417 47.425053]
  [42.302387 41.719414 41.152294 ... 45.83322  46.25723  46.69862 ]
  [41.767265 41.176807 40.6022   ... 45.10336  45.53409  45.982346]
  ...
  [34.871326 34.024693 33.186466 ... 38.512096 39.27535  40.047714]
  [35.281048 34.44434  33.61643  ... 38.854664 39.616066 40.38247 ]
  [35.71375  34.887276 34.069973 ... 39.219414 39.978626 40.73876 ]]

 [[43.45026  42.882713 42.330997 ... 47.10841  47.521156 47.951035]
  [42.906254 42.3315   41.77259  ... 46.377068 46.7962   47.232605]
  [42.37867  41.796745 41.223293 ... 45.655804 46.08143  46.524467]
  ...
  [35.227253 34.389256 33.560005 ... 39.06131  39.82936  40.59552 ]
  [35.632935 34.80457  33.985306 ... 39.3989   40.16079  40.925377]
  [36.061474 35.243042 34.434063 ... 39.75842  40.513924 41.276577]]

 [[44.061012 43.501347 42.957485 ... 47.65862  48.066692 48.49178 ]
  [43.52455  42.95454  42.393147 ... 46.93576  47.35     47.7814  ]
  [42.98583  42.401543 41.83282  ... 46.223125 46.643623 47.08143 ]
  ...
  [35.607372 34.778408 33.95852  ... 39.617744 40.382706 41.15282 ]
  [36.00883  35.18919  34.378963 ... 39.950607 40.70939  41.47392 ]
  [36.43301  35.622997 34.82272  ... 40.305264 41.057575 41.816097]]]
```

To better visualise this array I have created a plot:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [18.00, 14.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
data = sdf
z, x, y = data.nonzero()
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=z, alpha=1)
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='3D Array of Shape: (57, 90, 128)')
ax.legend(fontsize=25)
ax.set_xlabel('$Rows$', fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('$Columns$', fontsize=20)
ax.set_zlabel('$Order layers$', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image: 3D Array of Shape (57, 90, 128)]

My question is that can we understand this data structure to be (in this case) 57 matrices of shape (90, 128) stacked on top of each other?

For example;

i. Selects the second layer and all the rows and columns of that matrix?

```
x[1, :, :]
```

ii. Selects all the layers and the second row and all the columns?

```
x[:, 1, :]
```

iii. Selects all the layers and all the rows and the second column?

```
x[:, :, 1]
```

iv. Selects the first and second layers and the third and fourth rows and the fifth and sixth columns?

```
x[0:2, 3:5, 5:7]
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: yes, you can easily interpret it like that, even though I think that most people usually interprets the last layer as "row", not as "column"

Comment: also, you probably might prefer `scatter` to `plot`, https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html

Comment: Yes, I found that scatter has been a better option.